# Can't modify PATH during conda activate/deactivate

Tags: anaconda, conda

I am trying to use conda to manage c/c++ libraries as well as python at the same time, so I need to be able to modify $PATH for each environment separately. However, when I attempt to modify them using the prescribed methods shown at https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#saving-environment-variables, It does not work.

in etc/conda/activate.d/env_vars.sh I put something like

```
#!/bin/sh
export OLD_PATH=${PATH}
export PATH=/other/dir:/other/dir2:${PATH}
```

and in etc/conda/deactivate.d/env_vars.sh I put

```
#!/bin/sh
export PATH=${OLD_PATH}
unset OLD_PATH
```

I have tested that both scripts are being executed, and the activation script works as expected, and the deactivate script runs as well, and removes '/other/dir:/other/dir2' from PATH. However, conda appears to re-add '/other/dir:/other/dir2' to the PATH, and they are still present in the base environment once deactivation is complete.

Comment: This is probably because the activate command already adds to the PATH, so conda is trying to make sure it doesn't delete things it shouldn't. Do you need to do this?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes.. I have some third-party packages that I need to use. I don't want to install them into the conda environment directory to avoid name clashes and the like, so I need to be able to be able to modify the path. I just did some searching through the conda github, and it looks like they are planning no addressing this soon, so hopefully it will be fixed in the near future. Thanks for your help!